# How to create dict from pandas dataframe with headers as keys and column values as arrays (not lists)?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe of size (3x10000). I need to create a dict such that the keys are column headers and column values are arrays.

I understand there are many options to create such a dict where values are saved as lists. But I could not find a way to have the values as arrays.

Dataframe example:

```
     A   B   C
0    1   4   5
1    6   3   2
2    8   0   9
```

Expected output:

```
{'A': array([1, 6, 8, ...]),
 'B': array([4, 3, 0, ...]),
 'C': array([5, 2, 9, ...])}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess following does what you need:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # assuming df is your dataframe
>>> result = {header: np.array(df[header]) for header in df.columns}
>>> result
>>> {'A': array([1, 6, 8]), 'B': array([4, 3, 0]), 'C': array([5, 2, 9])
```

pandas added `to_numpy` in 0.24 and it should be way more efficient so you might want to check it.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html